# Whenever I try parsing JSON file I get KeyError in Python

Tags: python, json, api, google-maps, keyerror

I am using Google Maps API
Here is my code:

```
import googlemaps
import urllib2
import json

apiKey = '****************************'
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?departure_time=now&origin='
origin = raw_input("Origin ")
destination = raw_input("Destination ")
finalUrl = url + origin + '&destination=' + destination + '&key=' + apiKey

json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(finalUrl)
data = json.load(json_obj)

for item in data['routes']:
    print item['duration_in_traffic']
```

This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Documents/python/map2.py", line 15, in
>
> print item['duration_in_traffic']
>
> KeyError: 'duration_in_traffic'

I have gone through the JSON file and that key is definitely there.

Here is the item

> {u'routes': [{u'overview_polyline': {u'points':
>   u'cxuyH_|Mf@bB~BsB?A?A?C@IYyAOw@EAGKCQ@I@A_@[OYU_@]eAoAeEaBsHk@gCu@uC_@oAWk@Y]SM_Aa@iAe@_F}@oDk@q@GgAAoBHwAHiCPoAHsA@o@@aDd@g@LkAHs@AgC[s@CoA[kAKEqBKsAw@gFwBcNoAmJg@_F'},
>   u'warnings': [], u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 51.5752274,
>   u'lng': 0.09127539999999999}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 51.5615695,
>   u'lng': 0.0758157}}, u'waypoint_order': [], u'summary': u'Ley St',
>   u'copyrights': u'Map data \xa92015 Google', u'legs': [{u'distance':
>   {u'text': u'2.3 km', u'value': 2293}, u'end_address': u'Ilford,
>   Ilford, Greater London IG2, UK', u'via_waypoint': [],
>   u'duration_in_traffic': {u'text': u'5 mins', u'value': 315},
>   u'start_address': u'Ilford, Ilford, Greater London IG1, UK',
>   u'start_location': {u'lat': 51.5624203, u'lng': 0.0763182}, u'steps':
>   [{u'html_instructions': u'Head **southwest** on **Thorold Rd**
>   toward **Adelaide Rd**', u'distance': {u'text': u'42 m', u'value':
>   42}, u'travel_mode': u'DRIVING', u'start_location': {u'lat':
>   51.5624203, u'lng': 0.0763182}, u'polyline': {u'points': u'cxuyH_|Mb@zABF'}, u'duration': {u'text': u'1 min', u'value': 6},
>   u'end_location': {u'lat': 51.5622154, u'lng': 0.0758157}},
>   {u'html_instructions': u'Turn **left** at **Adelaide Rd**',
>   u'distance': {u'text': u'82 m', u'value': 82}, u'travel_mode':
>   u'DRIVING', u'maneuver': u'turn-left', u'start_location': {u'lat':
>   51.5622154, u'lng': 0.0758157}, u'polyline': {u'points': u'{vuyH{xM~BsB'}, u'duration': {u'text': u'1 min', u'value': 33},
>   u'end_location': {u'lat': 51.56157770000001, u'lng': 0.0763982}},
>   {u'html_instructions': u'At the roundabout, take the **1st** exit
>   onto **Hainault St**', u'distance': {u'text': u'62 m', u'value':
>   62}, u'travel_mode': u'DRIVING', u'maneuver': u'roundabout-left',
>   u'start_location': {u'lat': 51.56157770000001, u'lng': 0.0763982},
>   u'polyline': {u'points': u'{ruyHo|M?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A@??AU_ACYKw@'},
>   u'duration': {u'text': u'1 min', u'value': 16}, u'end_location':
>   {u'lat': 51.5617618, u'lng': 0.0772199}}, {u'html_instructions': u'At
>   the roundabout, take the **1st** exit onto **Ley St**',
>   u'distance': {u'text': u'1.5 km', u'value': 1539}, u'travel_mode':
>   u'DRIVING', u'maneuver': u'roundabout-left', u'start_location':
>   {u'lat': 51.5617618, u'lng': 0.0772199}, u'polyline': {u'points':
>   u'*tuyHsaNA?A?A?A??AA?AAA??AAA?AA??A?AAA?A?A?A?AAA?A?A?A?A@??A?A?A?A@A*@[OYU_@]eAoAeEaBsHYwAQo@?Eu@oCUw@IWIUMUEKSQKIGCq@[MEiAe@*F}@KAcDi@q@GgAAsAD[Bi@Bm@D{@HmAFoAHsA@o@@aDd@G@*@JcAFG@s@AgC[s@CoA[i@G'},
>   u'duration': {u'text': u'4 mins', u'value': 263}, u'end_location':
>   {u'lat': 51.5734933, u'lng': 0.08373649999999999}},
>   {u'html_instructions': u'Turn **right** onto **Eastern
>   Ave**/**A12**Destination will be on
>   the left', u'distance': {u'text': u'0.6 km', u'value': 568},
>   u'travel_mode': u'DRIVING', u'maneuver': u'turn-right',
>   u'start_location': {u'lat': 51.5734933, u'lng': 0.08373649999999999},
>   u'polyline': {u'points':
>   u'i}wyHkjOa@CA}@Cs@Eq@Ea@EYYqBSmACMMw@SsA]yBw@}Ey@eGGg@E_@G_@[mCKqA'},
>   u'duration': {u'text': u'1 min', u'value': 81}, u'end_location':
>   {u'lat': 51.5752274, u'lng': 0.09127539999999999}}], u'duration':
>   {u'text': u'7 mins', u'value': 399}, u'end_location': {u'lat':
>   51.5752274, u'lng': 0.09127539999999999}}]}], u'status': u'OK', u'geocoded_waypoints': [{u'place_id': u'ChIJA-CogdWl2EcRwTLERk1SnHY',
>   u'geocoder_status': u'OK', u'types': [u'postal_code_prefix',
>   u'postal_code']}, {u'place_id': u'ChIJSdgOJwWk2EcR_xRqH8zm13o',
>   u'geocoder_status': u'OK', u'types': [u'postal_code_prefix',
>   u'postal_code']}]}

Comment: Your code is broken. Are you sure that’s your code? Please post the full error stack trace.

Comment: The code works. I just can't make It show a specific part from json file.

Comment: The code here has syntax errors that are even visible from the syntax highlighting. And it doesn’t match your error message either.

Comment: `for item in data['routes]:` there is a missing ending quotation mark. `print item[duration_in_traffic]` there are no quotation marks at all. Anyway, consider printing out the `item` to see what kind of keys there are in the dictionary. Because apparently, the key is *not* there (Python is not lying about this).

Comment: I have added the item in the question. 'duration_in_traffic' is definitely there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item` does not contain a `duration_in_traffic` key.

For your example output, the correct path to the `duration_in_traffic` value is `item['legs'][0]['duration_in_traffic']`.

Comment: So how would I write that out instead of what I have now?

Comment: Instead of `print item['duration_in_traffic']` you do `print item['legs'][0]['duration_in_traffic']`?